# I need to query sum of values daily which occurred between specific time intervals of the day

Tags: sql, datetime, ms-access, sum

Hello everyone and thanks for the attention. I am working on an automation project and i need to implement a daily production log that uses an .mdb file. I keep writing on this database values i get from the plc on a main register table called "tab1". This table holds all daily registers of all days, like an historian. this is all good. Now i need to use these records to something i need. I will have to display 2 production indicators, (tagval_confirmados and tagval_indeterminados) that occurred between specific times of the day.

I currently have a sample database like that below. (ts is timestamp when process begin and when it ends.)

[tab1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqs6Q.png)

I have to provide the sum o values (tagval_confirmados and tagval_indeterminados) that were registered from:

- 06:00:00 to 07:00:00 -> tagval confirmados = ... ; tagval_indeterminados =...
- 07:00:00 to 08:00:00 -> tagval confirmados = ... ; tagval_indeterminados =...
- 08:00:00 to 09:00:00 -> tagval confirmados = ... ; tagval_indeterminados =...
  ...
- 18:00:00 to 19:00:00 -> tagval confirmados = ... ; tagval_indeterminados =...

So basically when today time is 07:00:00 i need to to have the sum of all(tagval_confirmados) and the sum of all (tagval_indeterminados) between 06:00:00 and 07:00:00 that i will use in another program via vbs script. Then when the today time is 08:00:00 i need to repeat this procedure with the same sum but between 07:00:00 to 08:00:00. I need advice or recommendation o how would be the best way to do it or the resources i would need. I currently have a basic knowledge of SQL. Should i create more tables to organize better the data ? Or i can use queries to perform what i need ?

I thanks any advice.

Comment: What is your desired result? Hourly aggregation? New calculated `sum` columns adjacent to original columns? Single row calculation based on `now()` time?

Comment: Thank you for the response my friend. In my table i got 2 columns with date/time variables. One is the start time and the other is the end time. I need to keep track of the actual date/time so i can know when to trigger the specific query. Let's say that today is 13/02/2020 14:37. As the hour is between 14:00 and 15:00 i will need to know when it gets to 15:00 so i can trigger a query that will sort production between 14:00 and 15:00. After 15:00, when it gets to 16:00 i will need to execute another quey, this time with production from 15:00 to 16:00. I need to sum all "tagval_confirmados".

Comment: Please post in the body of your question the current data and desired result in tabular format.